# How can I also make enter add input text in edittext to my listview? On top of the created add button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a button "add" which adds input text from the `editText` into a `listview` below. However, can I make it possible to add text to the created list by simply pressing enter? If so, how can i do that in a simple manner?

```
Name=edittext, list =listview

@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name = Name.getText().toString();
            if (Name.length() > 0) {
                list.add(name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: pressing enter, you mean when the user is typing in the editText and then he presses enter?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I now have a button "add that adds to the list" however i also want to make this same action possible simply by pressing enter

Comment: understood. try one of the following answers we posted.

Comment: super thanks a lot will try now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Handle "Enter" in an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/6832095
Here is what you need to do to capture Enter event on editText :

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It is better to flag the question as a duplicate of another question instead of copying an exact [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832095/7461132). @ShubhamSrivastava

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite your dispatchKeyEvent something like this

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
    Toast.makeText(UITestsActivity.this,
               "YOU CLICKED ENTER KEY",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```

Comment: only i havnt used a dispatchkeyevent in my code. So do i just try the above without having used a dispatchkeyevent with my code so far?

Comment: if you override this method then that particular activity will start listening to Enter key. so in the code above, instead of a Toast, get text from edittext and append it to the list or follow Shubham's answer

Comment: dispatchKeyEvent is a method of Activity. you should be able to override it by pressing (Ctrl+o) in Android Studio and look for dispatchKeyEvent method

Comment: still having trouble translating this to my specific code:

Comment: do you mind sharing your activity code? I will try to modify my answer to your needs
Also have a look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593286/android-edittext-enter-key-listener

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, therefore adding an answer. Building over previous answer, to achieve your function use this code:

```
import android.app.LauncherActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Name;
    Button Add;
    ListView Lv;
    Button Reset;
    Button Sgame;

    private ImageView information;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Playername);
        Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Addbutton);
        Lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Resetbutton);
        Sgame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Startgamebutton);

        information = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.constrain);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewlayout, R.id.list_content, list);
        Lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        final EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Playername);
        class MyKeyListener implements View.OnKeyListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    String name = Name.getText().toString();
                    if (Name.length() > 0) {
                        list.add(name);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                        return true;
                    }
                return false;
                }

        }
        Name.setOnKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());

        Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                if (Name.length() > 0) {
                    list.add(name);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    ;
                }
            }
        });

        Reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list.clear();

            }
        });

        Sgame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!list.isEmpty())
                    openActivity2();
            }
        });

        information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.informationpopup, null);

                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 1150, 2000, true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 140, 300);

                container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gamescreen.class);
        String s= list.get(0);
        intent.putExtra("Name1", s);
        startActivity(intent);
    }}
```

Comment: only here youve removed the add button possibility to add the edit text to the listview, however i want to both make it possibly through enter, or through pressing the add button

Comment: Okay so add the button feature back. I've added the feature by `ENTER` key in the above code. Refer it and add the button feature back again.

Comment: Oke lets see: https://gyazo.com/447ed3ab3ac67e566dd8b59d36e81277. Few red lines unrecognised commands. Left the button feature in it now.

Comment: You need to import the class KeyEvent:

`import android.view.KeyEvent;`. Just hover over the red line and you will see an option to correct imports by pressing Alt+Enter.

Comment: alright @Abhi, Ive added this (resolved the red lines) now I just have a compliation error (Just posted updated code as an answer)

Comment: What error do you receive? Post your stacktrace. Also edit your original question and post your results instead of posting new answers. It is creating too much noise in the whole post

Comment: Check the edited answer. I have corrected your code and it works now.

Comment: Only problems I still have is that the keyboard appears immediately upon start up (rather i want it to appear when clicking on the edit text field -> likewise dissapear on enter click/add button).  https://gyazo.com/c870f868424dc40e79bf1ee5f2c3c74a. Secondly when you type in a name and add through enter or add button the entered name remains in the edit text field (I really want it to clear after adding and make it say player ... in the field again -> see image: https://gyazo.com/2673d1903015e718db5588d2ee188a17. Is it possible you can help me with this. Im asking a lot im sorry :(

Comment: Post a new question and I will surely help. This is because the original question has been answered and future users may get confused with the extra code.